# How can I see BigQuery Storage API Logs?

Tags: google-bigquery, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to perform a log analysis for BigQuery. Unfortunately, I cannot find calls to the Bigquery Storage API (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc) in Stackdriver.

To generate some traceable logs I executed the following (modified) code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq

df_rest = pd.read_gbq(
    "SELECT something as rest_api_call FROM my_test_table", 
    use_bqstorage_api=False
)

df_storage = pd.read_gbq(
    "SELECT something as storage_api_call FROM my_test_table", 
    use_bqstorage_api=True
)
```

The REST API call can be found in the logs viewer https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer under the resource *BigQuery*. I cannot find the logs corresponding to the Storage API call. Does anybody know where I can find them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment because the API calls don't generally generate logs in Stackdriver. Metrics are accessible through the  APIs & Services menu.

A public feature request was opened in the Google [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159125960).
Please star the Feature Request if you come across this problem.